# Get artifact from other repo

Tags: github-actions

I have a private GitHub repository A that builds a library via GitHub Actions and uploads the built library as artifact at the end of the build workflow. This repository including the built library has to stay private due to license reasons.

Another public repository B should now link against that library during its GitHub Actions based build workflow. I only know the usual `upload-artifact` and `download-artifact` actions that can be used to manage actions within a workflow, but this does not seem like a solution to my problem.

Is there any official way to achieve what I want, is there any trick that could be used to make it work or is this simply not possible? If so, do you have recommendations for an alternative approach?

Comment: Extracting the `artifactId` after generating it could be an option, that way you could use it in another workflow (for example using an input or a dispatch event) consuming the [github API to download artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#download-an-artifact) directly.

Comment: I'm not sure if what I'll tell you helps, but you can access from workflow in github project A another github project by using the tag token in https://github.com/actions/checkout, where you will set as a secret your Personal Access Token of Github, to which you need to give permissions of accessing other workflows

Comment: So while being in workflow of B project, you can checkout project A and access it.

Answer (score 4):

I realized it would be a lot easier to access release assets of repository A instead of workflow artifacts. There are multiple ready-to-use actions that allow uploading releases from within a workflow run.

I created a private and a public test repository where the private repository has a single release with a simple text file asset and the public repository has a simple Actions workflow that fetches the asset from the private repo. It uses GitHub CLI with a command like `gh release download --repo <my/private-repo> <tag>`. You find the repository [here](https://github.com/JanosGit/download-release-from-private-repo-test).